# Bootstrap 4 & column with full length hr

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to make a horizontal line extend across the column width specified by the bootstrap parent element. I am using Bootstrap 4.1.1. the code is as follows.

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5">
        <p>Something here!</p>
        <hr/>
        <p>This list!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `<hr>` tag inherits parent `<div>` property and that prevents the `<hr>` tag to extend up to the length of the bootstrap's container class.

js fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/7gu21n8z/

Comment: hr {
  width: 100vw;
}

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap-4 has removed all the variants of `*-xs-*` classes. So instead of `col-xs-5`, you should use `col-5`. But if you want to have full width column, use either `col-12` or `col`.

#### col-12

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
        <p>Something here!</p>
        <hr/>
        <p>This list!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### col

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <p>Something here!</p>
        <hr/>
        <p>This list!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Doing so, the `hr` tag's width is equal to the width of the column minus its padding. But if you want `100vw` `hr`,  use the `hr` tag outside of the container.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as class 'col-xs-*' in bootstrap 4.

Use `col-12` class instead of col-xs-5 for the hr to take complete width